# Is there a time when the apps OnStart method is called more than once. If yes, why does it recommend to place AppCenter.Start there?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Looking for some advice on where to place OnStart.  I heard the OnStart even could be called more than once so I am confused as to why it is suggested to place the AppCenter.Start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a time when the apps OnStart method is called more than once?

The Application class contains three virtual methods that can be overridden to respond to lifecycle changes:

**OnStart** - called when the application starts.

**OnSleep** - called each time the application goes to the background.

**OnResume** - called when the application is resumed, after being sent to the background.

**OnSleep** and **OnResume** will been called multi-times when the app switched between background and foreground

The **OnStart** method will be called on rotation as well as when the application first starts, if the main activity lacks `ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation in the [Activity()] attribute` only **in Android** .

So for the most part it will only been called once .

Comment: Hi, So getting back to my question.  If the OnStart is called every time there is a rotation then why do the docs for AppCenter recommend to place AppCenter.Start in the OnStart method?  Any ideas?

Comment: As I said ,  for the most part it will only been called once  You just need to add the attribute to Android . On iOS it will work as expected .